# Compute standard error from beta, p-value, sample size, and the number of regression parameters

Tags: p-value, standard-error

How do I compute the standard error if I only know the p-value, the beta (i.e., the regression coefficient from a linear regression), the sample size, and the number of regression parameters?

Comment: What does "beta" represent here? I'm guessing regression coefficients?

Comment: Yes it does! Regression coefficients from a linear regression.

Comment: Then please edit your question and add this information. Short answer: No, you need the residual degrees of freedom (or sample size and number of regression parameters). Just the coefficient and the p-value is not enough.

Comment: Thank you! I will edit the question, as I actually do have the sample size, just not in the file I was looking at :) Thank you!

Comment: As I said: The sample size alone is still not enough: You need to know how many variables were included in the regression models.

Comment: Yes I just did! :)

Comment: The standard error of what estimate, exactly?  Of the betas?  $R^2$?  Residual variance?  Something else?

Comment: The standard error of the beta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a linear regression, the $p$-value is calculated from a $t$-value, which is the coefficient divided by its standard error ($t=\hat{\beta}/\mathrm{SE}_{\hat{\beta}}$). The degrees of freedom used in the $t$-distribution for calculating the $p$-value are the residual degrees of freedom ($\mathrm{SE}_{\hat{\beta}}=\hat{\beta}/|t|$). The residual degrees of freedom, on the other hand are the total degrees of freedom of the variance $N-1$ minus the model degrees of freedom $k-1$, where $k$ is the number of parameters including the intercept. So the residual degrees of freedom are $(N-1)-(k-1) = N-k$.

From this, you can use the quantile distribution of the $t$-distribution to calculate the standard error. Example: Assume that $\hat{\beta}=5.47, p = 0.004, N = 100, k = 4$. The residual degrees of freedom are $100-4 = 96$. We assume that the $p$-value is two-sided.

Using `R`, the calculations are:

```
t_val <- qt(0.004/2, df = 96) # Calculating the t-value using quantile function
5.47/abs(t_val) # Calculating standard error
1.854659
```

So the standard error was 1.85.

Comment: Does this also work for t-tests?

Comment: @Papayapap Sure, because $t$-tests are nothing else as regression models with categorical predictors. For a two-sample $t$-test, the predictor is binary and for the one-sample/paired $t$-test there is only an intercept.